# Sql Server Fulltext index behavior

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, full-text-indexing

I have a very weird problem with my fulltext index on my table.

I have this two strings index

```
1234567 This a shop
7654321 A shop
```

This query works fine:

```
SELECT *
FROM CONTAINSTABLE([MyTable], ([SearchableString]), '1234567') res
```

this one does not

```
SELECT *
FROM CONTAINSTABLE([MyTable], ([SearchableString]), '7654321') res
```

If I inspect the index with this query:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document( DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyTable') ) kbd
WHERE kbd.display_term LIKE '1234567%'
ORDER BY document_id, display_term;
```

The display_term is **1234567**

Doing the same query with the search criteria

```
SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document( DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID('dbo.MyTable') ) kbd
WHERE kbd.display_term LIKE '7654321%'
ORDER BY document_id, display_term;
```

The display_term is **7654321 a**

I was expecting to have a display_term like **7654321**

Why is this happening and how to tell the full text index to stop indexing things like that.